# Release Configuration Xamarin.Android Failing To Build

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, release

I've been trying to archive my xamarin.android project for publishing but I keep getting this error:

```
Error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed
```

I've searched this error and tried the suggestions that I came across and none of them worked. One weird thing I noticed though is that when I set the build configuration to `Debug` instead of build `Release` the project builds and runs perfectly fine. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set MSBuild to diagnostic level logging, clean and rebuild and post the full error message stack

Comment: Why don't you put down what you have tried, i think that makes sense as people don't go out of their way to suggest things you have already tried

Comment: @SushiHangover that will be about 10000 lines of log

Comment: @MichaelRandall ? **"full error message stack"** A `LinkAssemblies` error stack is around 12 lines that shows the failure point

Comment: @SushiHangover yeah sorry was on a different tangent , carry on :)

Comment: Try to set "Linking" option to "None" in project properties -> Android Options -> Linking. And see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: its quite big Michaels right

Comment: @Vahid I've tried that already it doesn't work

Comment: @Sushi Here's a paste bin https://pastebin.com/raw/aP9vgPVp

Comment: @Michael I've tried changing the linking option, I've tried updating my android sdk,  I tried changing the android target version,  Only thing I never tried is uninstalling and reinstalling the Xamarin.Forms package - these are among some of the most commonly suggested solutions

Comment: @CliftonSteenkamp What version of the `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` package are you using?

Comment: have you done this ? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/android-linkassemblies-error/

Comment: Its version 2.0.0

Comment: Yip I've tried that :)

Comment: anyone find anything interesting?